# implemention of python builtin function

Tags: python, built-in

I'm a freshman in python and I want to study the implemention of python's builtin function like `abs()`, but in the python file of `\__builtin__.py` I saw this:

[image: builtin_abs_function]

Does anybody know how it works?

Comment: Cpython implementation has a repository on [github](https://github.com/python/cpython)

Comment: Actually, the oficial one is on [hg.python.org](https://hg.python.org/cpython/)

Comment: @TimFuchs yeah, but the github one is easier to browse, and is *mostly* kept in sync

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: Looks like you're using PyCharm or something to view the definition - obviously this isn't the real one.

Answer (score 5):

The built-in functions are implemented in the same language as the interpreter, so the source code is different depending on the Python implementation you are using (Jython, CPython, PyPy, etc). You are probably using CPython, so the `abs()` function is implemented in C. You can look at the real source code of this function [here](https://hg.python.org/coding/cpython/file/tip/Python/bltinmodule.c#l245).

```
static PyObject *
builtin_abs(PyObject *module, PyObject *x)
{
    return PyNumber_Absolute(x);
}
```

The source code for `PyNumber_Absolute` (which is, arguably, more interesting) can be found [here](https://hg.python.org/coding/cpython/file/tip/Objects/abstract.c#l1165):

```
PyObject *
PyNumber_Absolute(PyObject *o)
{
    PyNumberMethods *m;

   if (o == NULL)
        return null_error();
    m = o->ob_type->tp_as_number;
    if (m && m->nb_absolute)
        return m->nb_absolute(o);

    return type_error("bad operand type for abs(): '%.200s'", o);
}
```

As you can see, the actual implementation of `abs()` calls `nb_absolute()` which is different for different object types. The one for float looks [like this](https://hg.python.org/coding/cpython/file/tip/Objects/floatobject.c#l802)

```
static PyObject *
float_abs(PyFloatObject *v)
{
    return PyFloat_FromDouble(fabs(v->ob_fval));
}
```

So, effectively, CPython is just using the C math library in this case. The same will be true for other implementations of Python - Jython is using the functions from the Java math library.